# How to handle reCAPTCHA Enterprise with Cloud Armour redirect

Tags: angular, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, recaptcha, recaptcha-enterprise

I have implemented reCAPTCHA Enterprise with Cloud Armour integration in an Angular v16 app and it is working as expected when blocking or allowing traffic. However I am unsure how to implement a redirect \ challenge.

What I am trying to do is

- block low scores (working)
- accept high scores (working)
- challenge medium scores (how to display the challenge page?)
  [image]

From the logs I can see the cloud armour session tokens are valid

```
securityPolicyRequestData: {
   recaptchaSessionToken: {
   score: 0.89999998
   }}
   statusDetails: "response_sent_by_backend"
}
```

On the front end the HTTP GET requests return either the expected result from the backend or HTML which seems to be a reCAPTCHA challenge page which needs to be displayed somehow

```
const response$ = this.httpClient.post(url,  body, options );
```

response$ is sometimes the challenge page HTML e.g.

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en-US" dir="ltr"><head><base href="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/challengep........
```

So if `response$` is HTML - how to display it?

I've tried just setting the HTML

```
reCaptchaRender(body: string) {
    let recaptchaDOMElem = document.getElementById('recaptcha')
    recaptchaDOMElem!.innerHTML = body
}
```

and also a component with DOMSanitizer but the result is the same

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-recaptcha',
  templateUrl: './recaptcha.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recaptcha.component.scss']
})
export class MyRecaptcha {

  @ViewChild('recaptcha') recaptcha: ElementRef | undefined;

  private _html: string = ''

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  @Input() 
    public set recaptchaHTML(val: string) {
      this._html = val;
      if (this.recaptcha) {
        this.recaptcha.nativeElement.innerHTML = (
          this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML,  this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this._html))
        )}
  }
}
```

However that just results in

[image]

And the overlay which should be the pictures with the challenge is never displayed.

There are 404 errors in the logs which may or may not be relevant

```
httpRequest: {
latency: "0.223792s"
remoteIp: "xxx.16.32.252"
requestMethod: "GET"
requestSize: "18"
requestUrl: "https://app.xxxxxxxx.com/_/mss/boq-recaptcha/_/ss/k=boq-recaptcha.RecaptchaChallengePageUi.rMQB95nZlqc.L.B1.O/am=BMO0/d=1/ed=1/rs=AP105ZiCwi8N5mUj4UtZch0cdCHAP5fEfQ/chrome.css.map"
responseSize: "168"
status: 404
userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}
insertId: "6nvowkfrbxo3o"
```

So how do you handle the challenge page?

**UPDATE**
I have stripped it back to just a static page calling a static page.
As soon as `document.close();` is called, reCAPTCHA tries to establish a connection to its service and is rejected by CORS

The error is

```
start:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/challengepage/_/RecaptchaChallengePageUi/browserinfo?f.sid=-6482627183065648936&bl=boq_recaptcha-boq-challengepage_20231012.04_p0&hl=en-US&_reqid=70468&rt=j' from origin 
'https://my-domain.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.


       POST https://www.google.com/recaptcha/challengepage/_/RecaptchaChallengePageUi/browserinfo?f.sid=-6482627183065648936&bl=boq_recaptcha-boq-
challengepage_20231012.04_p0&hl=en-US&_reqid=70468&rt=j net::ERR_FAILED
```

My App is
Create a Session token and associate it with the security policy

```
gcloud recaptcha keys create \
        --web \
        --display-name=$RE_CAPTCHA_KEY_NAME  \
        --integration-type=score \
        --domains=$APP_ENGINE_URL \
        --waf-feature=session-token \
        --waf-service=CA
gcloud beta compute security-policies update $CLOUD_ARMOUR_SEC_NAME \
        --recaptcha-redirect-site-key $RE_CAPTCHA_SITE_KEY \
        --enable-layer7-ddos-defense \
        --log-level=VERBOSE
```

Create the Cloud Armour Rule

```
gcloud beta compute security-policies rules create 1009 \
        --security-policy $CLOUD_ARMOUR_SEC_NAME  \
        --action redirect \
        --redirect-type=google-recaptcha \
        --expression=request.path.contains\(\'/login\'\)\ \&\&\ \(token.recaptcha_session.score\ \<\ 0.7\)
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: python311
env: standard

instance_class: F1

handlers:
- url: /login
  script: auto

- url: /start
  script: auto

- url: /
  script: auto
```

Flask back end

```
from flask import Flask, make_response, request, send_from_directory
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)  # Enable CORS for all routes

@app.route('/start', methods=['GET'])
def starter():
    return send_from_directory("./static", "starter.html")

@app.route('/login')
def login():

    return send_from_directory("./static", "mainapp.html")

@app.route('/')
@cross_origin(send_wildcard=True)
def index():
    return "Hello World"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

starter.html page

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta>
  <base href="/">
  <script
    src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?render=<SESSION_TOKEN_KEY>&waf=session"></script>
  <script>
    function goToApp() {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', 'https://my-domain/login', false);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          document.open();
          document.write(xhr.responseText);
          document.close(); //reCAPTURE fails on document.close()

        }
      };
      xhr.send(null);
    }

    onError = (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    }

    grecaptcha.enterprise.ready(function () {
      document.getElementById("launch-link").onclick = () => {
        grecaptcha.enterprise.execute('<SESSION_TOKEN_KEY>', {
        }).then(goToApp, onError);
      };
    });

  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <a href="#" id="launch-link">Launch The App</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

What am I missing? How to overcome the CORS issue blocking reCAPTCHA from rendering the challenge page?

Comment: In the reCAPTCHA key settings, under the WAF features, did you select "Challenge page"? https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/implement-waf-ca#redirect Here are some docs on how the redirect to the challenge page would work https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/examples-ca

Comment: Yes the key is a Challenge key and I can see the results are the HTML and Javascript reCAPTCHA page. The problem is that the Angular App does not show the popup with the pictures to choose from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cloud Armor challenge page redirect here is designed to protect a site on the HTTP routing level, not out of an API call made from a web app. A lower-score HTTP request is being 302 redirected to the Google challenge page, so even if you can figure out how to display that HTML on your own site, it won't properly generate reCAPTCHA tokens because they wouldn't come from the Google-hosted page.

If you're intending to just protect your own backend endpoint that you reach with a POST request, it'd be simpler to implement reCAPTCHA using the more traditional means of creating a token on your frontend & then calling createAssessment() with that token on your backend to see the score. See https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/setup-overview-web.

If you're intending to use a challenge page to generally guard your site and contents from bots, it's enough to put the Cloud Armor rules in place and let those redirect visitors to the challenge page on subsequent page loads after a low score is seen. You could exempt POST requests to your backend with additional firewall rules if it's intercepting those and shouldn't be.

Another consideration to make when using challenge pages -- if what you're protecting is valuable enough for an attacker to pay for a captcha-farm, challenge pages work against your by offering a way for attackers to end-run around your protection by intentionally generating a low score and then "redeeming" their sessions with a farmed challenge solve. In those cases you're better off using other means to redeem real users (redirect to login, 2FA, flag transaction for manual review, etc).

Comment: So if my aim is to protect a single page web app from bots, using a score based Session key should be enough?

Comment: Yes, although there's still a possibility that humans can get a low score behind VPNs, shared public IPs, etc. This is why the session token + challenge page for low score redemption is still a pretty common use case.

From taking another look at the screenshot, I think the issue is you're applying the firewall rules to your '/api' path, when you'd want it to apply to the main page the app is hosted on. Then low scoring visitors would be redirected to the challenge page before they can load your SPA, while higher scores would see no friction.

Comment: You might also consider adding an interstitial landing / loading page in front of the SPA at a different path to establish a score, as new visitors wouldn't have any session or challenge token to exempt or score their traffic.

Comment: Yep there is already a landing page & login page which is establishing a score but no conditions or redirects on it. Looking at that suggestion now

Comment: I have implemented the changes. However the main issue of being unable to render the challenge page persists.

Comment: The issue is that as soon as document.close(); is called, reCAPTURE throws the CORS errors trying to establish a connection to its service. Is there any sample code or guidance on showing the challenge page for a session token?

Comment: Rim Vilgalys - I've accepted the answer as it got me on the right track. Thank you. However the redirect rules from Cloud Armour will still not display the challenge page. I'll ask it as a new question